# Excel formula to search each record and find highest/lowest number for each date group

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, formulas, array-formulas

I have a Worksheet that has a large dataset. Each record has a unique job number. Each job has a range of unique control numbers associated with it. There are many jobs performed each day. In other words, there might be 30+ jobs associated with each date, and each job has a varying amount of control numbers, anywhere from 1 to 500+. I am looking for a formula that would find the first and last control number for each date. In other words, I want to search the DatePrinted column (A) for all jobs performed on (ex.)7/1/2015, and find the first control number from the first job and the last control number from the last job on that date. I want to put this into another worksheet in the same workbook.

Comment: See [MINIF, MAXIF and MODEIF](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/wiki/office_2013_release-excel/minif-maxif-and-modeif-with-standard-formulas/144a2f30-31ef-408e-86c3-f1443d9ac1fd).

Comment: I checked that article, and it was very helpful. Thank you for the link in regards to minif and maxif. However, I am still having a bit of difficulty getting the answer that I want. The formula will not be using a defined range of cells because each day has a varying number of jobs. Also, July 1 might have more jobs than August 1, so although using a defined range might work for July, it might cut off some of the jobs in August. I would like the formula to be dynamic enough to recognize that. Does this make sense?

Comment: This is what I came up with, but it returns "0". Any ideas why? =MAX(IF(A3:A9999=DATEVALUE("5/1/2015"), K3:L403))

Comment: Are A3:A9999 just dates or datetimes? `K3:L403` needs to be the same size as A3:A9999 (e.g. `K3:L9999`). Try `=MAX(IF(A3:A9999>=DATE(2015, 5, 1), IF(A3:A9999<DATE(2015, 5, 2), K3:L9999)))` . (btw, this banter is why sample data together with expected results is important)

Comment: A3 to A9999 are datetimes. This is how they are formatted (7/13/2015 8:57:11 AM) I tried the formula you suggested above, but it returned the largest control number (K3:L9999) from 5/31/2015, and not 5/1/15.

Answer (score 0):

If A3:A9999 are datetimes, then you will not get an exact *equals* match to any particular day unless the time portion was exactly midnight. You need to provide a *scope* where the datetimes can be compared to *greater than or equal to* AND *less than*. Try,

```
=MAX(IF(A3:A9999>=DATE(2015, 5, 1), IF(A3:A9999<DATE(2015, 5, 2), K3:L9999)))
```

I've use the [DATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATE-function-B91BEF00-4B5B-4EE0-B80E-06E68B1DFF29) instead of the [DATEVALUE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATEVALUE-function-b5bd5892-0c18-4c78-be4a-d7b5b3525e23) but that is just personal preference. Assuming a MDY regional system format you could use `>=DATEVALUE("5/1/2015")` and `<DATEVALUE("5/2/2015")` instead if you prefer.

Also note that I've adjusted the `K3:L403` cell range to `K3:L9999` in order to match the criteria range(s).

Comment: This is definitely progress as now I am actually getting the maximum value in the k3:L9999 range. However, the max is coming from the largest number in the range (5/31/2015), and not the largest number from 5/1/2015 when using the date fuction. Also, I formatted the A column to display just the date, without actually changing the data.

Comment: In the row(s) containing datetimes where the date portion is 5/1/2015, it will return the largest value from *either* column K or column L. Beyond that observation, I would need to see sample data as I proofed the formula before submitting it and it was returning the correct results for me.

Comment: I'm having a hard time including sample data that is legible into this thread. What is the best way to include tabular data that stays formatted.

Comment: Column K would be the starting control number for that job (row), and column L would be the ending number, so it's fine that max and min would  return the values from either column. However, it's still returning the max control number for the entire month, and not just the first. Might it have something to do with the way the dates are formatted in Column A? They are pasted into excel from an Oracle application and are functional links back to that website. They are datetimes (5/13/2015  9:25:16 AM) but i formatted the column to just display a simple m/d/yyyy format.

Comment: Additionally, when I change the date in the formula, it returns zero. For example, >=DATE("2015,5,2), IF(A3:A9999<DATE(2015,5,3) it will return a zero. The only time it returns a figure is when the date is greater than or equal to one. eg. >=DATE("2015,5,1"), and even then the number that it returns is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped. It did work after all. I was simply forgetting to press Ctrl-Shift-Enter upon leaving the cell